# Cannot get object data from custom query Back& - Backand.com - Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, backand

This is my get method to get object from Backend Service

```
// LocationService add, update, delete, etc
.service('LocationService', function ($http, Backand) {

// Initiation the opject 
var baseUrl = '/1/objects/';
var objectName = 'location/';
var query ='/1/query/data/';

function getUrl() {
 return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName;
}

function getUrlForId(id) {
 return getUrl() + id;
}

getLocations = function (id) {  

    var url = Backand.getApiUrl() + query + 'getLocationbyUserName?' + 'parameters=%7B%22Username%22:%22habibi%22%7D';
    //var url = 'https://api.backand.com/1/query/data/getLocationbyUserName?parameters=%7B%22Username%22:%22ha%22%7D';
    //var url = getUrlForId(id);
    return $http.get(url);
};
```

Add my controller

```
 LocationService.getLocations('2').then(function (result) {
                $scope.location = result.data;
                alert($scope.location.latitude);
                friendLatitude = $scope.location.latitude;
                friendLongtitude = $scope.location.longtitude;
 },function(error){
                console.log("LocationService cannot get friend location");
                    });
```

However, I got the result from $scope.location.latitude is undefined

Comment: could you add response here in question which you're server is responding?

Comment: I tried to get data by using id, it's successful. But, I want to get data by username, I used custom query on Backand, and it couldn't get data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you alert your result data, you'll see just charterers , the reason for that is the different responses between getting Geo location from an object and getting it from query. What you need to do is manipulate the query to return the latitude and longitude parsed from the object like that

```
SELECT CONCAT(X(`lat_long`), ',', Y(`lat_long`))  as origin
FROM `garages` 
WHERE (ST_Distance .........
```

Comment: I will try and let you know, Thanks u